# Total Size(Disk) Vs Total Size(Media)

Tags: backup, hardware, hard-drive

I'm using ArcServe Backup which backup hard-drive data to tape. I came across the following in the ArcServe Backup log file:

> Blockquote

Total Size (Disk)............ 67.02 MB

Total Size (Media)........... 913.12 MB

> Blockquote

What is the difference? and why the gap between those two numbers is so wide? 
Note: The above log entry was for an incremental backup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used ArcServe in quite a while, but to take a shot in the dark, I'd say the (disk) is referring to the storage on the hard disk that the files are taking up. I'd assume the media is the tap and the difference is that tape is probably logging full/incremental changes and over time, the tape will have a substantial amount more of data than the disk.

Although in your case x10 more storage used than the disk size is a little unusual, I can't help but wonder what your tape rotation scheme is. How long do you keep incremental backups? When you do a full backup, do you dump all the incremental backups prior to the full?